# Irreducible polynomial

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $\displaystyle (b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3)$ be a permutation of the set $\displaystyle  \{54,72,36,108\}$. Prove that $\displaystyle  x^5+b_3x^3+b_2x^2+b_1x+b_0$ is irreducible in $\displaystyle  \mathbb Z[x]$.

This was given me by my teacher in a problem sheet, I haven't done anything. I hope that there is a solution which does not consider $24$ permutations separately. A slick solution is welcomed.

Comment: Maybe the Eisenstein's criterion can help you out?

Comment: If $b_0 = 54$, then by Eisenstein using the prime $p = 2$, it is irreducible. At least that takes care of 6 cases. It won't help much in the other cases, though. At least not directly.

Comment: They are all multiples of $18$.